# How to Send Multiple CC Emails + Email Send Definition PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

How to Send Multiple CC Emails + Email Send Definition PHP

Working well with one CCEmail, but i want to send multiple ccemails.
I tried with comma separated, but it is not working.
Do we have any other we can add Multiple CC EMails

```
$emailSendDef = new ExactTarget_EmailSendDefinition();
$emailSendDef->CCEmail = $ccemail;
```

Comment: My self got the answer: Appending with semicolon(;) working.

Comment: Would you mind adding your answer and checking it when you can so we know this is answered. Thanks!

Comment: How can i make it as answered?

Comment: It allows you to check the checkmark after a day or so. Check back later and it will tell you if you can, or when you will be able. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Appending with semicolon(;) working.

Comment: Could you please add some more information about your solution?